# Yii2 Exception in ValidatePassword()

Tags: php, yii2

I use yii2 for developing web site.
Before save user to db, I encripted password like this:

```
$this->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($this->password);
```

And when I use this code:

```
Yii::$app->security->validatePassword("some string", $this->password);
```

I have error:

> Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException
>   Hash is invalid.

What is wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/security-passwords.md
lhs $hash

Comment: what is the value of $this->password when you generate password hash?

Also check the two template model LoginForm and User in common/models how yii2 is using this to login

Comment: Problem solved, i has type of field password varchar(20)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. I realized that my password field's character capacity was too short for the hash, so I bumped it up from varchar(25) to varchar(255).

Answer (score 0):

make sureyou have a column name exactly as password_hash in the user table and change your code from

Yii::$app->security->validatePassword("some string", $this->password);

to:

Yii::$app->security->validatePassword("some string", $this->password_hash);

Comment: Low quality as a comment.